# How to generate messages with maui c# et google calendar

Tags: c#, android, calendar, maui

Hi from Marseille france

I am developing an app with maui c# android and I would like to be able to generate messages with the Google calendar to remind the user to do something at a date/time. Is this possible and which API to use?
thanks a lot

My application ends and I miss this function. I have browsed the technical press on the internet but without success

Comment: You are looking for this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager. Also, if you google "Reminder App Xamarin", you will have tons of code to reuse for MAUI.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create events in Google Calendar by using the Google Calendar API.

You can use any HTTP client library to make a call to the API and insert an event. When creating the event you can add a reminder to the event which will display a message to the user.

The following has a code example of how to build the event and post it to the API using:

```
service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId);
```

where the service is your http client service.

There is a code example here:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert